# No keyboard after suspension on Debian Testing

Tags: debian, keyboard, suspend

all.

I run kernel 5.14.16-1 on Debian Testing.

My suspension sequence includes locking the screen with Xscreensaver. Everytime I resume from suspension, I have no keyboard; I do have trackpad mobility and therefore I can click on the "New Login" button on the prompt given by Xscreensaver; however, I still have no keyboard when I do this, so it's irrelevant. I've tried the solutions posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916465/ubuntu-17-04-keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend) (all of them) but they don't work; they all propose adding/removing kernel booting parameters.

Today I found this on `dmesg`:

```
[  830.452644] i8042: Can't write CTR while closing AUX port
[  830.999579] i8042: Can't reactivate AUX port
[  831.003094] atkbd serio0: Spurious ACK on isa0060/serio0. Some program might be trying to access hardware directly.
```

Perhaps this can help me figure out what is going on, but searching for this term only returns the methods I've already tried.

Also, today I noticed that connecting a USB keyboard works; moreover, when I press any key on the USB keyboard, my laptop's starts working again.

Is there a way of automating this after resuming from suspension? That is, "fooling" the kernel into believing there is a USB keyboard and that a key was pressed in it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your laptop's model Dell or VAIO? 
If so, maybe your problem is related to [Bug 195471](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195471). 
It's a bug that has been present in the Linux kernel since a few years ago.

I have a VAIO laptop affected with that bug, and I have found two workarounds:

1. After resume **to not** press any key but <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, wait a couple of seconds until the Caps Lock LED turns on, and then my keyboard works normally.
2. If you're willing to compile the module yourself, take a look [to this patched kernel module](https://github.com/Tedyst/i8042-SonyLaptop/), it even includes a systemd service unit that restarts the driver after resume, so this is more a fix than a workaround, but I doubt it would be merged to upstream kernels as it seems that the models affected are not that many.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had seen that bug; and quite so, pressing CapsLock repeatedly unlocks the keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On a "Sony Vaio Fit SVF152A29M" with kernel 5.15.0-58 (Ubuntu 22.04) the hint from the kernel bug https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195471 helped:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and modify the default line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd"
```

Then run update-grub and reboot.

After suspending the caps lock and num lock leds are on, but the keyboard works.

---

Removing the i8042 kernel module before sleeping and after suspending makes the LEDs work: https://github.com/mistine/i8042-keyboard-fix-linux